# How strongly does the number of processors influence on the performance?

Tags: performance, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, multi-core

I use Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V. I can increase the number of processors in Hyper-V settings (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQCMT-O6bMM).

How strongly it will increase the performance?

My question is: Why there are only 4 processers in the base settings of Hyper-V 2008R2? So I set 24 processers (I have 24 cores) will I increase perfomance? How much it will increase?

Update

Thanks for everyone. The question is closed.

Comment: Only you can answer most of this by testing your machine in your environment running your workload. Oh and what has this to do with Ubuntu ?

Comment: It is the part of the question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74288/what-are-the-best-options-for-os-ubuntu-with-osm-planet

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can only be answered by thoroughly testing in the OPs environment with the OPs workload.


Comment: Actually it can be answered - it also depends on the workload. Is the software used capable of using more than one processors? TWO will likely help generally - the OS can use the second processor for somet things even if the first is busy from the application. But software ascalability in a multi processor scenario is something that the producer of the software has to answer to. And we dont even know.... what softtware is talked of.

Comment: @TomTom, based on his other questions here and other stackexchange sites, I suspect he's talking about ESRI ArcMap. His other question in the GIS SE site linked to various articles and basically answered this question already if the application will take advantage of multi-cores. In addition, specifically with ESRI, there are licensing considerations he will need to deal with for ArcMap and multiple processors.

Comment: @Rex can not comment on that - never used that, dont know it. I was more answering in general. Licensing - yes, that can be nasty. Oracle is also famour for that - and now MIcrosoft SQL Server join the hell. Good this was answered to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of Hyper-V 2008 R2. The first being that all 24 cores are generally going to be accessible and can generally be used by the host (The physical machine running Hyper-V and the Hyper-V hypervisor itself). The 2nd being that 2008 R2 has a maximum of 4 cores that can be assigned to each guest virtual machine running on top of the Hyper-V hypervisor. The third, your performance increase (or decrease) would be highly depending on the application you are running within the virtual machine running on the physical host and what load any other virtual machines you might have running on top of the host are generating.

edit:
To answer the question for your edit: It's limited to 4 because that is the amount that Microsoft deemed would be supported in that version of Hyper-V. If you want a deeper answer than that, call up Microsoft support and ask them.

Comment: TO add: If you need more than 4 processors in a virtual machine, update your OLD AND OUTDATED HYPER-V. 2012 raied the limit significantly. 2012 R2 adds even more ion the dscalability level - and is jsut some days away. So, thif you need more , there is more - just use it properly.

Comment: Can I install HYPER-V 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: No. Hyper-V 2012 replaces 2008 R2. novicegis - I understand you might be a "novice". This board is for professional admins. If you do no understand from answers to your previous posts here and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73843/can-i-increase-the-number-of-processes-in-arcgis-server-10-1 what you are looking for, I suggest you reach out to ESRI support for the answers you really need.

Comment: The comment of TomTom is incorrect.

Comment: @novicegis you can believe what you choose to believe. TomTom is correct in that only 4 processors are supported in Hyper-V 2008 R2. Yes, you can hack your way into the XML file to manually increase it, but I would not run your production GIS system in an unsupported configuration. Choosing to do so would be ill advised, ill fated, and illogical.

Comment: Especially when basically all that is required is a free update of the technology stack (asuming hyper-v server is used) and there are a LOT of other advatnages with it. Production exxpensive software on hacked configurations - admins REALLY try to hit a new low of professionalism these days. Sorry to be blunt. I Want to be able to call support for my production machines.